# Multiple file upload with okhttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I've been struggling with this code for many hours. Can someone guide me where i missed? If upload one file, it's successful. When i change code to multiple file, it will error.
Here is my okhttp JSONParser.java

```
public static JSONObject uploadImage(ArrayList<String> photoCaptions) {


    try {

            String photoUrl = photoCaptions.get(0);
            String photoUrl2 = photoCaptions.get(1);
            String photoUrl3 = photoCaptions.get(2);

            File sourceFile = new File(photoUrl);
            File sourceFile2 = new File(photoUrl2);
            File sourceFile3 = new File(photoUrl3);

            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/*");

            String filename = photoUrl.substring(photoUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            String filename2 = photoUrl2.substring(photoUrl2.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            String filename3 = photoUrl2.substring(photoUrl2.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

            Log.d("TAG", "File...::::" + sourceFile.getName() + " : "+ photoUrl + " - " + sourceFile.exists());


        MultipartBody.Builder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        RequestBody requestBody = multipartBuilder
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image1", filename, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                .addFormDataPart("image2", filename2, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile2))
                .addFormDataPart("image3", filename3, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile3))

                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL_UPLOAD_IMAGE)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String res = response.body().string();
        Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + res);
        return new JSONObject(res);



    } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the error

```
02-15 02:15:20.425 27709-27821/com.domain.appgallery E/TAG: Other Error: End of input at character 0 of
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 

//importing dbDetails file 
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//this is our upload folder 
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

//Getting the server ip 
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

//creating the upload url 
$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/gallery/'.$upload_path; 

//response array 
$response = array(); 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request 
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){

        //connecting to the database 
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request 
        //$name = $_POST['name'];

        //getting file info from the request 
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

        //getting the file extension 
        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        //file url to store in the database 
        $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

        //file path to upload in the server 
        $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension; 

        //trying to save the file in the directory 
        try{
            //saving the file 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `photos` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_url', NULL);";

            //adding the path and name to database 
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                //filling response array with values 
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                //$response['name'] = $name;
                $response['result'] = 'success';

            }
        //if some error occurred 
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        }       
        //displaying the response 
        echo json_encode($response);

        //closing the connection 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Please choose a file';
    }
}

/*
    We are generating the file name 
    so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload 
*/
function getFileName(){
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
    $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM photos";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    mysqli_close($con);
    if($result['id']==null)
        return 1; 
    else 
        return ++$result['id']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my bad.
I haven't look at php code at all. 
Added for loop to handle images.
And alter some type in android.

Now it works.